# Running an Excel File following Successful Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement, process.start

I am trying to put together some code that requires users to enter in their current windows username and password, in order to run an excel file. However, I am having trouble with the *process.start* portion of my code. Not sure what I am missing.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool LogonUser(string userName, string domainName, string password, int LogonType, int LogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool issuccess = false;
            string username = GetloggedinUserName();

            if (username.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(txtUserName.Text.Trim().ToLowerInvariant()) && username.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(txtDomain.Text.Trim().ToLowerInvariant()))
            {
                issuccess = IsValidateCredentials(txtUserName.Text.Trim(), txtPwd.Text.Trim(), txtDomain.Text.Trim());
            }

            if (issuccess)
                MessageBox.Show("Successfuly Login !!!");

// Here is where I am having trouble. I cannot get this file to run. 

                Process.Start("Z:\\FolderA\\Test.xlsx");


            else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username and/or Password Combination. Please try again. ");
        }

        private string GetloggedinUserName()
        {
            System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            return currentUser.Name;
        }

        private bool IsValidateCredentials(string userName, string password, string domain)
        {
            IntPtr tokenHandler = IntPtr.Zero;
            bool isValid = LogonUser(userName, domain, password, 2, 0, ref tokenHandler);
            return isValid;
        }

        private void ButtonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

- Visual Studio Error Messages:

> Severity Code Description
>       Error CS0103  The name 'Process' does not exist in the current context    TestApp C:\C#\Windows Authentication\C#\TestApp\Form1.cs
>       Error CS1513  } expected  TestApp C:\C#\Windows Authentication\C#\TestApp\Form1.cs

Comment: Please add exact error message/exception you are getting. Also please clarify whether your actual code compiles or not and make sure [MCVE] you've posted in the question reflects your actual problem. So far code just syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Side note: please don't add "thank you" notes, story of your life (new here/new to language) and tags in title when creating posts on SO.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Foremost, I find propriety in disporting aforehand appreciation. Adventitiously, to the former part of your statement: I was reproached in one of my earlier posts for providing error messages, so...I am a little confused. In all candor, yet with deference, I am aware of the fact the that my code is "syntactically incorrect". That is why I am asking for help. Regardless, thank you for your constructive criticism. Have a wonder day

Comment: Side Note: It will compile if I remove the process start. –

Comment: Please check using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");`

Comment: Always provide error messages. Also note that a compile error means it has nothing to do with Process or other subjects but with invalid C#. As noted below, use `{}`

Comment: Thanks @ Emmanuel Ponnudurai! Your suggestion + the solution below worked great. There is a bit of a learning curve going from python to C#. Thank you everyone for your contribution, constructive criticism and patients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing braces in your `IF` statement:

```
        if (issuccess)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Successfuly Login !!!");
            Process.Start("Z:\\FolderA\\Test.xlsx");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username and/or Password Combination. Please try again. ");
        }
```

It is a safe rule to always use braces for multi-line IF statements.